# AngularJS: How to execute a controller function AFTER completion of AJAX call in a service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Here's my code in the service.

```
this.loginUser = function(checkUser) {
    Parse.User.logIn(checkUser.username, checkUser.password, {
        success: function(user) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function (){
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Here's my code in the controller:

```
$scope.logIn = function(){
    authenticationService.loginUser($scope.checkUser);
        console.log($scope.currentUser)
};
```

So, what I want to do is, execute some code AFTER the completion of AJAX call, whose success function sets the value of $scope.currentUser, which, I can use for some conditional logic (like redirecting etc)
The success function is correctly setting the value, but the `console.log` should be executed AFTER the execution of `authenticationService.loginUser()` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to return a promise using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) and act on that.

For instance in your service:

```
this.loginUser = function(checkUser) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Parse.User.logIn(checkUser.username, checkUser.password, {
        success: function(user) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function (){
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;
            });
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then in your controller act on the success:

```
$scope.logIn = function(){
    authenticationService.loginUser($scope.checkUser).then(function() {
        console.log($rootScope.currentUser));
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried this. But my `console.log($scope.currentUser)` still does not log the new value of currentUser (set by success function of ajax call in service.)

Comment: I made an edit.  The service is setting the current user on $rootScope, the controller was looking at $scope.currentUser and that should have been $rootScope.currentUser.

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thanks :-)
Although I've been suggested that using $rootScope is bad practice. I'm now trying to refactor my code so as to remove the use of $rootScope from my service. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$rootScope.$broadcast` in your service then listen for it in your controller:

Service

```
Parse.User.logIn(checkUser.username, checkUser.password, {
    success: function(user) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function (){
            $rootScope.currentUser = user;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('user.online');
        });
    }
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.$on('user.online',function(){
    [ DO STUFF HERE ]
});
```

This isn't the best way to do this though @comradburk's use of $q is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If your application wait for external result, you should use $q for return a promise. If you are using `angular-route` or `ui-router` components, you can use `resolve` param for this. Take a look `ngRoute` documentation. In there has a example based in resolve param.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

i think you have two options here

1. as answered by comradburk, use promises:

in Services:

```
this.loginUser = function(checkUser) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
Parse.User.logIn(checkUser.username, checkUser.password, {
    success: function(user) {
        deferred.resolve(user);
    }
});
return deferred.promise;
```

};

in controller:

```
$scope.logIn = function(){
authenticationService.loginUser($scope.checkUser).then(function(user) {
    $scope.currentUser = user;
});
};
```

1. using resolve, resolve your service at route level (...or state level in case you are using ui-router) before controller initialization and insert it as a dependency - helpful in scenarios like user authentication where you dont want user to be able to navigate further if authentication fails. from docs 
   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

YOMS (Yet One More Solution):

```
    this.loginUser = function(checkUser, onSuccess) {
        Parse.User.logIn(checkUser.username, checkUser.password, {
            success: function(user) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                    if (typeof onSuccess == 'function') onSuccess(user); // optionally pass data back
                });
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.logIn = function(user, function(returnedUser) {
    // console.log(returnedUser); // Optional, The returned user
        console.log($scope.currentUser)
    }) {
        authenticationService.loginUser($scope.checkUser);
    };
```

Comment: for a more "angularjs" way of doing the same, see @comradburk answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23546890/572771