# HTML Page loads before AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

In my HTML Page, I have a `button` tag that looks like so:

```
<button ng-hide="alreadyFreinds()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Friend</button>
```

However, when I try to access certain parts of the `alreadyFriends` function shown below, I get an error saying that  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
  $scope.alreadyFreinds = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.user.friends.length; i++){
      if($scope.user.friends[i].username === $scope.realUserViewing.username && 
        $scope.user.friends[i].requested == true && $scope.user.friends[i].pending == true){
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
```

However, the confusing part is that I already have $scope.user.friends and $scope.user defined in a few lines above this function like so:

```
  $http.get('/api/users/me')
    .then(function(result){
      $scope.user = result.data;
  });
```

I am a bit confused as to why the HTML page loads and calls tbe alreadyFriends function before the Ajax call completes. I tried to use promises to help me solve this and I found

[AngularJS: How to execute a controller function AFTER completion of AJAX call in a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546593/angularjs-how-to-execute-a-controller-function-after-completion-of-ajax-call-in)

But this did not help me too much because when I did

```
  $http.get('/api/users/me')
    .then(function(result){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $scope.user = result.data;
      deferred.resolve($scope.alreadyFreinds);
      return deferred.promise;
  });
```

This did work, but the HTML page still loads up before the AJAX call is completed. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: One way would be to resolve the 'user' in your route? That way, you will have it ready in your controller right at the beginning. Have you tried that via 'resolve' instead of making the ajax call in the controller?

Comment: @CMR ah i see. I have not used that before, nor have I heard of it. I will take a look into that then. Would you give me any tips on how to use it?

Comment: Take a look at this example.[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example].

Comment: have you added the $scope to your controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button ng-hide="alreadyFreinds()" 
     ng-if="user.length > 0"
     type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Friend</button>
```

By setting `ng-if` your button will be visible and your `alreadyFreinds()` will be fired when your http call response get back.

Comment: This wouldn't work for what I am trying to do. I am trying to see if the user.friends[i] == requested & user.friends[i] == pending. It's not if user.length is > 0.

Comment: but you should wait until the http callbacks get back and then fire your function *alreadyFreinds*, let me update example

Comment: Interesting. Well my ng-if keeps evaluating to be false which is now making the button disappear now.. Any ideas on how to prevent this? It is weird: I don't even enter the alreadyFreinds() function with this ng-if statement